# Alterar valores de chave de registro Windows

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, visual-basic-6

É possível construir uma aplicação a qual a mesma procura uma chave no registro do Windows com um nome exato e ao encontrar alterar seu valor por um valor definido pelo usuário?

Se possível qual a melhor linguagem para implementar isto? VB.NET?!

Comment: Parece me que a tua pergunta está muito ampla. Para não falar que és capaz de estar a infringir algum termo de uso da Microsoft :P

Comment: É possível, já fiz algo similar em C++.

Comment: @CesarMiguel não acho que infrinja nenhuma lei. Sendo que é apenas um software que faz exatamente a mesma coisa que você pode fazer manualmente, não tem como você ter um privilégio extra só pq está alterando chaves através de código.

Comment: @Math, eu apenas deduzi que pudesse infringir. Agora se o faz ou não, não sei. Mas realmente és capaz de ter razão :)

Comment: Tem alguma instrução a mais a me dá @Math?! Uma luz, um caminho? :D Não sei por onde começar...

Comment: @Luitame a resposta abaixo deve te ajudar. Se fosse em C++ eu diria para usar `TRegistry`.

Comment: Vlw @Math... Vi a resposta agora! Abs

Answer (score 6):

Sim, é possivel.

Em C#:

```
using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("oMeuCaminho"))
{
    if (key != null) 
        key.SetValue("nomeDaMinhaChave", "valorDaMinhaChave", RegistryValueKind.String);
}
```

Ou em VB.NET:

```
Registry.SetValue("oMeuCaminho", "nomeDaMinhaChave", "valorDaMinhaChave")
```

([Mais informações sobre a classe Registry na MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.Win32.Registry%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

Comment: vlw! @Omni pelo feedback...

Answer (score 0):

a melhor maneira que encontrei foi essa

```
c#

const string userRoot = @"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings";
           // onde "1" vc habilita o proxy e "0" vc desabilita.
            Registry.SetValue(userRoot, "ProxyEnable", "1", RegistryValueKind.DWord);
          // informe o endereço ip junto da porta para acesso ao proxy, vazio "" desabilita função
            Registry.SetValue(userRoot, "ProxyServer", "192.168.0.254:2555", RegistryValueKind.String);
```